# How to change the selected text icons color on Maui Android?

Tags: android, maui

How can I change the color of the purple icons that appear when I select text in a Maui Editor control on Android? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color in the Platforms -> Android -> Resources -> values -> colors.xml.

```
<color name="colorAccent">#ff0000</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Platforms > Android > Resources > values > colors.xml

Clean & Build/Rebuild and you should be good to go!